# Reset value of odometry data when start to run app

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
Is there any way to reset the value of odometry sensor node in ROS turtlebot, because when I restart my app the turtlebot still turn on the odometry data is still display the value of the previous running

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193735/reset-value-of-odometry-data-when-start-to-run-app/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which turtlebot is it? The odometry usually depends on the hardware.

The [kobuki_node](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_node) has a service `~commands/reset_odometry` that does exactly what you want.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1